# How to know what is the proper heap size for Java app (Spring app)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, memory, jvm

I have a Spring Boot backend application, so I wonder how much memory should I give it? Currently, I give about 1GB to it and it seems to work (not sure what should I check).

However, I have heard people saying that *Java is memory-intensive and one should give it about 1:4 CPU:Memory (i.e. if 4 core cpu, then 16GB memory). Currently my Spring uses 3~6cpu cores, but only 1~2 GB of memory. So I am quite confused. Am I wrong? What should I do?

Thank you!

More details: It connects to MySQL, Redis, etc, and does not have many memory-heavy things inside itself.

More details: GC and memory usage captured by Micrometer & Prometheus & Grafana:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can make pressure test for your spring boot application,if current memory is enough,so you no need to modify it.

Comment: @TongChen I do make stress test. The screenshot comes from stress test actually. Juding from it, is it enough?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider doing a load test to see how the application is going to behave under pressure in a production environment, create a load test suite using [Soap Ui](https://www.soapui.org/docs/load-testing/getting-started/) or some similar tool and run it in ramp-up mode to see how the application is going to use CPU and memory, as I'm seeing above you don't have any major GC frequently which means that you don't have any memory consuming operations in the application, but to be sure any way you will need to do a load test, and don't forget to profile your application during the load test ([YourKit-preferred](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/cpu_profiling.jsp), VisualVm). and from the results, you can decide how much memory you will need to assign for different segments of the GC ([JVM Parameters](https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-parameters)), also you can decide on which garbage collector you will need to use(CMS, G1,... ) [Garbage collectors](https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-garbage-collectors).

Comment: I do make stress test. The screenshot comes from stress test actually :)

Comment: "you can decide how much memory you will need to assign for different segments of the GC" -> how can I decide, could you please elabolerate?

Comment: Please refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/6n5srlhqf/index.html